# Use of " " in R

Tags: r

I have just started to learn for my school class. How does the "  " function in R?

Here is my code:

```
filter(mpg, cyl = 8)
filter(mpg, cyl = "8")
```

When I run the code, the first code's result and the second code's result are the same.

I would like to know the difference between these codes.

Comment: I don't think that is your code. If it were, it would give an error because it should use "==", not "=".

Answer (score 1):

There are several different kinds of values ("types") that can be stored in R:  numbers (there are three kinds of those), character strings, etc.  When you write `8`, you are writing a number.  When you write `"8"`, you are writing a character string.

Other possible numbers are `3.14159`, `-3`, and some exotic things like `Inf` (infinity!).  Other possible character strings are `"Hello"`, `"Ça va"`, and `"你好"`.

If you mix types in an expression, R will convert one or the other.  So `cyl` (which holds numbers) can be compared to the character string `"8"` by converting the numbers to character strings.  This leads to oddities like

```r
2 > "10"
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

It is `TRUE` because `2` gets converted to `"2"` and that comes alphabetically later than `"10"`.